# Security error on sql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a .net 2.0 (3.5, using a 2.0 application pool) application.  The code is hosted on a file share and the application pool user account is a domain account that is in the IIS_iUSR group and has read/write access to the share.

It was working fine on one server, but we had to move it to another server.  Now as soon as it hits a piece of code that uses SQL server client I get this error:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

I set up the CAS policy to fully trust that share according to this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx but it's still not working.

It's not SQL server permissions, the connection account has connection and owner privileges on the database.

How do I get this working?

Comment: you have to delete all the project files and re-compile it

Comment: it sounds you have deplaced or copied the project between OS or Machines

Comment: Check your web.config for the CAS policy. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583158(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @k3rnel There are no project files, just deployed code. The code wasn't copied, per se, this is a new server pointing to the old code

Comment: @Max I set trust="Full" in web.config and I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue: apparently the only thing that qualifies as "intranet_zone" is a netbios name for the server.  We were using an IP address, which is evaluated as "internet zone". I put our internal file server IP in the host file and redid the physical path and all is well.